# jQuery addClass not working dynamicaly generated php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php argument and i'm trying to add a class using jQuery, based on the outcome of the php argument, I cant see why this is not woking. any help greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$image_overlay = 'Yes';

if($image_overlay == 'Yes'){
    $overlay_outcome = 'Yes';
}else{
    $overlay_outcome = 'No';
}
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var overlay = <?php echo $overlay_outcome; ?>

        if (overlay == 'Yes') {
            $(".product a.jq-target").addClass("image-overlay");
        }
        else {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="product">
    <a class="jq-target" href="#">

    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you should have an error in your console, right?! See Gautam's answer to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace like

```
var overlay = '<?php echo $overlay_outcome; ?>';
```

Try to check the console while you doing this.It will display the syntax errors in your code.